# javascript Regex verfiy list separated by commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to prepare regex which must  verify list separated by commas
Requirement is

1. Check if list is separated by commas
2. There must be no trailing comma/commas
3. ,, is not allowed ; there must be word inbetween commas
4. there must be atleast one comma

**JS :** https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/yyw29bj8/4/

```
//check if list is separated by commas
//There must be no trailing comma/commas
// ,, is not allowed ; there must be word inbetween commas
// there must be atleast one comma

var test = function(STR) {
  return /[-\w\s]+(,[-\w\s]+)*/g.test(STR);
}


//must Pass
console.log('===== PASS ============');
console.log(test('1000,two thousand,3000'));
console.log(test('1000 , 2000 , 3000'));
console.log(test('First Option,2Nd Option, THIRD Option'));

//must fail
console.log('===== FAIL ============');
console.log(test('Single Value'));
console.log(test('1000 ,, 2000 , 3000'));
console.log(test('1000 , 2000 , 3000,'));
console.log(test(',,1000 , 2000 , 3000'));
console.log(test('1000 , 2000 , 3000,,'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `/g` since you are using `RegExp.test()`, add anchors `^` and `$` (to disallow partial matches) and replace the `*` with the `+` quantifier (to require at least one comma):

```
/^[-\w\s]+(,[-\w\s]+)+$/.test(STR);
 ^                   ^^
```

See  the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0aencjum/) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG0sB6/1) (I replaced `\s` with regular spaces for demo purposes).

If you want to avoid validating sequences like `---,----`, you can further enhance the regex like:

```
^\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(?:\s*,\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)+\s*$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mS3aS6/2) and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0aencjum/1/).

This regex matches any string with leading/trailing optional spaces (due to `^\s*` and `\s*$`), that starts with a word followed with zero or more spaces + words (with `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*`) and this can be followed 1 or more times with optional spaces, comma, and a word followed with spaces +  words (0 or more times).

Comment: Works like a charm .. Thankx

Comment: Glad to help. I forgot to use `\s` in the second regex suggestion, updated it now. Regular spaces are necessary so that the demo results might not get distorted and wrong lines do not get highlighted (as if matched).